# git init error: unable to create directory for .git/HEAD [inside htdocs/]

Tags: git, msysgit

when I try to create a repo inside htdocs folder of my Apache installation (using Zend Server CE) git gives me this error:

```
  $ git init  
  error: unable to create directory for e:/WORK/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/gittest2/.git/HEAD
```

It works well outside htdocs/, but i would like to have repos inside this dir in order to work on them at the same time.

I have been using git bash with administrator privilages and AFAIR there's nothing else that could be wrong regarding privilages on Win machines.

Any help will be appreciated!

Using:

- Win7 x64
- git installed from msysGit -> Git-1.6.5.1-preview20091022.exe

---

### [update]

- as VonC suggested it might be a bug in this release of msysGit

## Workaround

Use TortoiseGit to create a repo in the directory that's causing you problems. Good chance it will be successfull.

Sometimes Git GUI (from msysgit) will successfully create a 'troublesome' repo (worked on my last repo in this folder, not this one though).

Comment: Aside from using another app like TortoiseGit the git 1.7 is giving me the same problem.  Still unsolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be related to a bug with Git1.6.5.1 on 64 bit: this [Japanese tweet mentions](http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=L40&q=git+getara+msysgit&btnG=Rechercher&meta=&aq=f&oq=)

> msysgit 1.6.5.1 だと"error: unable to create directory for [project]/.git/HEAD."とか言ってリポジトリが作れなかった。
>   散々悩んだ後、1.6.3.2にバージョン下げたらあっさり成功

Which Google ruffly translates as:

> it msysgit 1.6.5.1 "error: unable to create directory for [project] / .git / HEAD." Nor could they pull the repository including me.
>   After the devastating agony, 1.6.3.2 version下Getara success lightly

So a downgrade to 1.6.3.2 could be the answer here.
But I did not found any [opened bug supporting that](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/list).

<sup>As they say: なんじゃこりゃ。(WTF) ;)</sup>

Check also (if you are using a TortoiseGit), to use the 64-bit version and not the 32-bits one.

Comment: Thanks for the response, you gave me and idea. I will try to use TortoiseGit to init a repo, since i'm using git bash purely. I will update on this

Comment: As i tought, I was able to create a repo using TortoiseGit. I am now able to work on this using git bash.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the permissions on the folders htdocs/ and gittest2/. Enable both read and write permissions.

Comment: I gave full control on these 2 folder to all the groups/users on my system. The error is still the same.

Comment: Are you able to create a directory there by hand from shell?

Comment: Yes I can create folders and files there using git bash, even smt like touch .git/HEAD will work manually

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of (I thought I did that already!....) I found out what my problem was - as I read this thread and only a few other areas.... (User Access Control on Windows Visa 32-bit).

Hope this helps someone else....

I had to unset UAC [uncheck] it.
And, then *reboot* - i did a soft (logoff) in my initial attempt.

Again, hope this helps.

Comment: why would it require UAC?